# What is headshot damage multiplier?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In CS headshots were 400% of the weapon's base damage.

What is the headshot damage multiplier in Counter Strike Global Offensive?

My friend said it was 2.5 or 2.66666 or 2.8

I want to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

As of 13/Feb/2014 it is still 400% based on a quick read of the linked chart.
http://www.schuzak.jp/cs-go/dmgchart.html